# Event Issue in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have this event in my `base.cmp`:

ResourcesLoaded.evt

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" access='global'>
</aura:event>
```

In my component I define the event like that:

```
<aura:registerEvent name='ResourcesLoaded' type='c:ResourcesLoaded' access='global' />
```

And I add an handler like that:

```
<aura:handler name="ResourcesLoaded" event="c:ResourcesLoaded" action="{!c.initializeComponent}"/>
```

I fire the `ResourcesLoaded` event after my scripts are loaded.

If I execute that, everything is fine and works correctly. But now, when I create another component and embedded my `base.cmp` and hooks myself on the `ResourcesLoaded` element like this:

```
<c:Base ResourcesLoaded="{!c.theThingsIHaveToDoWhenIamLoaded}" />
```

The `initializeComponent` is never called. [From the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_overview.htm), I think it should call both my `theThingsIHaveToDoWhenIamLoaded` and `initializeComponent` methods.

Is that a bug? I think it should be supported by lightning.

Comment: While embedding base component, you are passing resourcesLoaded in it. Is it attribute or event handler name?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in you are calling a child component method from parent  <s>`<c:Base ResourcesLoaded="{!c.theThingsIHaveToDoWhenIamLoaded}" />`</s>    you cannot call the method directly in markup you may set attribute values by passing it. You may `fire the event` in parent and in child handler can call the respective method .Or you can use `<aura:method>` to call the child method...